# Unity duplicate Node to content container

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Quick question. 
I have been looking around for days now, but somehow I can't get this to work.

I want to duplicate a Node box by a c# script to a content container [see image]. 
What is the best way to accomplish something like this in Unity and C#?

As I understand correct; this can be done with the Instantiate function right?

```
// get gameobject
public GameObject listpanel;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    // find tag
    listpanel = GameObject.Find("listpanel");

    // duplicate tag
    GameObject duplicate = Instantiate(listpanel);

    // set panel not active
    //listpanel.SetActive(!listpanel.activeSelf);
}
```

Anybody has an idea of what I am doing wrong here.

Help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

update: This ends in no errors at all at the console; it seems to work, but nothing shows up.

Wesley

Comment: What result are you getting, and what result are you expecting?

Comment: Any error message in the console?

Comment: I am expecting that the box will be copied, but nothing happens and no errors are shown.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have called?

Comment: !00% sure because when I use the "listpanel.SetActive(!listpanel.activeSelf);" it turns the listpanel inactive.

Comment: In your scene I see no object called `listpanel` ... You probably also want to Instantiate as a child inside a `Canvas` if this contains UI stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could share any errors that are in your console, it would help us debug.

For what I can see, if you are finding by tag, the **FindGameObjectsWithTag** method should be used instead of **Find**. This will be returned as an array.
Also, the **Instantiate** method has a number of parameters, where the 4th parameter would state what parent object it would be attached to.

Here is an example of instantiating a prefab located in the "Resources" folder of the Assets.
The prefab is instantiated as a child of another existing object.

```cs
  void Start()
  {
    //State what to instantiate, where, and the rotation
    GameObject nodeobject = (GameObject)Resources.Load("mynodeobject");
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,270,0);

    //State the parent object
    GameObject parentobject = GameObject.Find("ParentObject");

    //Instantiate the prefab
    Instantiate(nodeobject, position, rotation, parentobject.transform);
  }
```

Comment: Let me try it with that. Right now it doesn't really show any errors, to be honest.

Comment: You are a legend! It works indeed. Seems that I was doing it all wrong. Thank you for sending me in the right direction.

Comment: Great! Thanks for updating us :D